# How to use a serialized JSON object in js

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've serialized an object from java into a json object in a file and now I want to use its data. But I don't know how to get this file which contain only my JSON object. I want to get it into an js object that I can use in a script.

Comment: Do you mean `Java -> JSON -> Javascript` or `Java -> JSON -> Java` ?

Comment: I did Java -> json now I want to do JSON -> JavaScript

Comment: For the parsing you can take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935684/1938640) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11550982/1938640)

Comment: And do you intend to serve the JSON to clients? What platform do you use on your server?

Comment: I just want to use its data in a highcharts chart but I need to get it into a variable. @ZombieSpy the part i'm interested in is to put the JSON Object that is in a file into a variable

Comment: Which environment are you using - do you have web-server, Apache or similar, set up which could server the file for the JavaScript in browser, or are you planning to use it from node.js?

Comment: I'm working on a localserver

Comment: if on the localhost and for your own use one, JSON is JavaScript code so you might just create a HTML file and insert the JSON in <script> var data = <yourJSONHERE>;</script> and give that object to the chart

Comment: @mel so you are planning on shipping your computer? :p

Comment: Not yet^^ just training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550982/1938640) you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)'s [`getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

```
$.getJSON("/path/to/my/json_file.json", function (json) {
    imaginaryFunctionThatDoesMagicStuff(json);
});
```

Or if you can grab the file in other ways you can use the [javascript parse function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
JSON.parse(raw);
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935684/1938640)

---

Example:

```js
$.getJSON("http://json-stat.org/samples/order.json",function(data)
{
  document.write(data.order.label);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```